# Phonegap image is blurry and does not redraw that image after zoom

Tags: android, image, cordova, zooming, blurry

I have a very difficult problem here, i've been trying to find a solution for this for a while but failed. Maybe this is a Phonegap limitation or the OS Browser(which phonegap uses as webview) limitation. Im not sure..

Ok here's my problem..

I have a **4000x3000** image resolution and my Phonegap app has a functionality to zoom an html image or html text using css3 transform:scale()

First of all, testing on a DESKTOP web browser, when i zoom a high-resolution image and html text, the image and text gets blurry after the zoom. But after few milliseconds, the desktop browser redraws it which makes the image and text clearer. This is the default behaviour of the browser of course

Now in Phonegap side, by default i display the image via **< img >** tag and apply a css3 **transform:scale(0.5)** to make the image smaller to fit in mobile, now when i double tap the image, i will zoom it and apply the css3 **transform:scale(2.5)**

The problem in Phonegap is that when i zoom the image, phonegap does not redraw the image which makes the image blurry. Blurry Image is a big deal for me since there are texts inside the image and text when zoomed is not clear to read.

**And an important note, redrawing does not happen using a Samsung S3 with JellyBean OS version(Android), while in Xiaomi phone with KitKat OS version(Android), redrawing happens. I've also found similar problem in iOS7 using ipodtouch5**

Im not sure if this can be fixed via code or this is a browser limitation.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Hopefully anyone has solution out there.

Hoping for everyone's help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

This works for me on android and iOS (except WKWebView plugins).